# Load text after header.php has loaded

Tags: wordpress

I want to show some text after the header has loaded. I tried below,

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'menu_call', 100000 );
function menu_call() {
    echo "Menu has loaded";
}
```

But still the menu_call() is loaded before header.php content.

Comment: The [get_header action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_header) runs "**at the very start** of the get_header function call". If you want to insert some content to the document **body**, then you can't do it this way. Check if your theme has a custom hook you can use for this purpose, and it not you can always add it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

the next hook is "wp_head"

get_header = Fires before the header template file is loaded.
wp_head = Fire the wp_head action.

wp_head is also in header.php

the first wordPress hook that calls in the body is "loop_start". (i think)
maybe your theme has hooks between this